# How to perform arithmetic for a node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I have an array of boxes and I would like to number them quickly using TikZ. My idea was to use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
      \draw (\x*2-.5,\y*2-.5) rectangle (\x*2+.5,\y*2+.5) node[midway] {\x+1+5*\y};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, a node node now looks like `0+1+5*2` as an example. Is there someway I can get TikZ to convert `0+1+5*2` into `11`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need first to calculate value of the `\x+1+5*\y` and than use result as content of the node:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xy}{\x+1+5*\y} % macro which calculate value of \x+1+5*\y
        \draw (\x*8-1,\y*8+1) rectangle (\x*8+1,\y*8-1) node[midway] {\xy};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For use of the `pgfmath` library (it is loaded by default) see chapter *Mathematical and Object-Oriented Engines*, pp 1010 in `tikz` documentation (version for 4.1.4a), particular section *94.1 Parsing Expressions* on page 1012.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to build a table of square boxes `1 cm` wide and separated from each other by `1 cm`.

You can use `nodes` with a `minimum size` of `1cm`, with the `draw` option which by default draws their outline as a `rectangle`, here a square.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}{
    \foreach \y [evaluate =\y as \xy using int(\x+1+5*\y)]in {0,...,4}
      \node[draw,minimum size=1cm] at (2*\x,2*\y) {\xy};
      }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]